# What should be the color of the clothes worn by a temple priest?

Tags: rituals, priests

Is there any scripture which talks about the duties/rituals of a temple priest ? Like what should be the color of this clothes ? For temples of different deities, should the color of the priests' cloth also be different ?

Like for a priest of Shani Temple he should wear black, for priest of Vishnu Temple he should wear yellow, etc ?

Comment: I don't know if it answers, but a bramhachari wears white and a sanyasi wears ochre